# IlegalStateException: Cache already created: 'database-code'

Tags: database, jdbc, spring-jdbc, hikaricp, mssql-jdbc

I have a spring boot application where I use `mssql-jdbc` to connect to my sql-server database and I am using Hikari connection pool. There is a line of code in my application which creates a `HikaryDataSource` for a list of data sources in my application. The code looks like the following

```
for(HikaryConfig config: configs) {
   HikaryDatasource ds = new HikaryDataSource(config);
   // store the ds in HashMap for later use
}
```

The above code works fine and I was able to fill my HashMap with HikaryDataSources

I wanted to improve the above to use java `parallel-streams` to create the Datasources parallely. The changed code looks like the following

```
configs.parallelStream(config -> {
  HikaryDatasource ds = new HikaryDataSource(config);
   // store the ds in HashMap for later use
});
```

On the above implementation, some data sources are created and some failed with a message.

`IlegalStateException: Cache already created: 'database-code'`.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache already created: 'database-code' at org.cache2k.core.CacheManagerImpl.newCache(CacheManagerImpl.java:176) at org.cache2k.core.InternalCache2kBuilder.buildAsIs(InternalCache2kBuilder.java:266) at org.cache2k.core.InternalCache2kBuilder.build(InternalCache2kBuilder.java:202) at org.cache2k.core.Cache2kCoreProviderImpl.createCache(Cache2kCoreProviderImpl.java:228) at org.cache2k.Cache2kBuilder.build(Cache2kBuilder.java:933)`

I am wandering if the parallel-stream causes it